# S3 spool bucket / anonymous PUT

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, cors, spool

I'd like to use S3 CORS and key expiration to create a 'spool bucket'. This spool bucket should support the following:

- Frontend code (say, jQuery) should be able to `HTTP PUT` arbitrarily named keys to the bucket
- Backend code (say, Python/boto) should be able to read and delete these keys, given a key name
- keys should expire by themselves after X days

How exactly should this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some mucking about, here's what I found:

- Create a bucket
- Give *everyone* the permissions *Upload/Delete* and *Edit Permissions* (should be easy with the API, my case was easier with the console).
- Set the following (or similar) [CORS](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

- set an object [lifecycle](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) policy to match your wishes (again, easy with the API, easier in my case with the console)
- When doing your PUT, add the header `x-amz-acl: bucket-owner-full-control`. For example, in CoffeeScript and jQuery, your PUT will look like this:

```
$.ajax http://my_spool_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com,
    type: "PUT"
    data: "contents of new object"
    headers:
        "x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
```

That's it. Bask in the glory of highly available, self-expunging, CORS compatible, cheap and easy HTTP spool space. One important thing to remember: any client can overwrite any key; you should design accordingly (I use cryptographically secure generated keys).